# success.form.bv fires multiple times

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrapvalidator

I really need some help here with a form submission issue using BootstrapValidator.

I have the following code to call a page using AJAX, when I get a successfully response it refreshes the page with location.reload(true).

```
$('#indstillingForm1')
  .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
    // Prevent form submission
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get the form instance
    var $form = $(e.target);
    // Get the BootstrapValidator instance
    var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');
    $.ajax({
      url: "../bin/gem_indstilling.php",
      type: "POST",
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      dataType:"json",
      data: form_data,
      cache: false,
      success: function(response) {  
      if(response.result === "success") {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
        setTimeout(function(){
          location.reload(true);
        }, 2000);
      } else if(response.result === "failure") {
      }
    })
  });
});
```

The problem is that the .on('success.form.bv') code are triggered multiple times.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(response.result === "success") {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
        setTimeout(function(){
          location.reload(true);
        }, 2000);
      }
```

> I guess this is the problem as you are reloading the page again which causes to send same request again

Comment: But .on('success.form.bv') is only fired then the form #indstillingForm1 is submitted. Isn't it?
And a location.reload is not submitting the form.